# An array of possibilities on board

Tags: pattern, visual

[image: ?]

Draw or describe an image to replace the '?'.

WARNING: Contains added color and flavor.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> [image]

Reason:

> These are how chess figures can move. 
>  Pawn, Queen, Knight, Rook, King, (Bishop)

Additional explanation:

> The sunlight in the 1st picture is promotion.
>  The thing (dandelion?) on the ground is castling.

Comment: This has to be it - nice find!

Comment: @BaSzAt: That's it!  And although there could obviously be other images that would satisfy the required criterion, this is indeed the one that I had in mind!

Comment: Being vague since I don't know how to spoiler hide in comments: The first image is not missing what you suggest - it is not a special case in the way these things work for itself, just a special case with respect to the external thing.

Comment: @Chris Ah, I see what you're hinting at. Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Oh good. Because I had no idea how to be more precise without being spoilerish. Quite the puzzle in itself. ;-)

Comment: @Chris: Related: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/puzzling-design-pitch-congratulations-youre-graduating?cb=1#comment9950_4655

Comment: This seems right! But could there be more? Might be grasping at straws here, but 1. The sun shines uPAWN the ground, 2. The wheel of the ship QUEEN Mary, 3. A flower in the KNIGHT, 4. A Rook is a bird (No poetry here) 5. DandeLION is the KING of the jungle. So for the question, maybe you could do a Rosary with the cross at an angle to form the diagonal lines.

Comment: @knrumsey: At one point, I _was_ thinking of such added connotations but could only make it work for 3 and 4 (and maybe 5), so I gave up on that idea.  Interesting thought for 1!  :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> An image of a rainbow

Reasoning:

> The shown images seem to fit the story of Noah. At sea in a ship (image 2) for 40 days and nights (images 1 and 3). Noah sent out birds to see if there was land again (image 4) and one returned with a branch (image 5). The story ends with landfall and the rainbow.

Comment: Creative.  Fits loosely, though.  Image 5 doesn't have a bird and as for image 4 I doubt Noah had a periscope/telescope.  :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess.

> Image of an anchor.
>
> [image]

Reason.

> The sight of birds at sea is an indication that land is nearby, in the image after, clearly land is shown. So next step should be to port the ship and drop the "anchor".

Comment: Interesting extrapolation. But that's only taking into consideration 2 of the 5 images; so it's kind of like saying that the next number in the sequence {1,2,3,5,7,...} must be 9 when it should be 11.  I'll also add that the images aren't necessarily in a particular sequence.

Comment: @humn: Interesting image (and the re-edit makes it even more interesting).  Beats me what you had in mind there. :-) But, it looks like you might perhaps be focusing on the right characteristics.

Comment: Was just trying to make it look like an anchor, @KeyboardWielder, "matching" the necessary 45-degree essence of the puzzle (the re-edit barely missed the 5-minute precipice)

Comment: @humn Do you have a drawing setting called "matchstick"?

Comment: Handmade, @SendersReagent, inspired by 5th image in the array

Comment: @humn Wow. They look *a lot* like strike-anywhere matches.

Comment: Right on, @SendersReagent, just hope that Abhishek doesn't mind that they struck here

Comment: The 5th image is actually supposed to look like dandelion seeds, but feel free to think of them as matchsticks if you want.  :)

Comment: @KeyboardWielder - Well I for one thought they looked like dandelion seeds floating around (with tails)

Comment: @humn: Your 3 versions of anchors form 3 different answers.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder "the images aren't necessarily in a particular sequence. " by this do you mean you are just looking for an image which is related to the other 5 and sequence of images has nothing to do with the solution ?

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes.  But related in a very strong definite way.